# Oracle Pivot retornando mais de uma linha

Tags: oracle, procedure, pivot, scripting

tudo bem pessoal?
to com um problema aqui.

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
 SELECT /*+parallel(12)+*/ DES_REGIS,                       
                          DES_CONTR,     
                          COMPRAS_OFFUS_PARC_COM_JUROS,        
                          COMPRAS_OFFUS_PARC_SEM_JUROS, 
                          COMPRAS_OFFUS_AVISTA, 
                          COMPRAS_ONUS_PARC_COM_JUROS, 
                          COMPRAS_ONUS_AVISTA, 
                          COMPRAS_ONUS_PARC_SEM_JUROS, 
                          DESCONTOS, 
                          IOF, 
                          JUROS, 
                          MULTA, 
                          OUTROS, 
                          PAGAMENTOS, 
                          PAG_CONTAS, 
                          PARCELE, 
                          RECUPERA, 
                          SAQUE_PARCELADO, 
                          SAQUE_AVISTA, 
                          SEGUROS,
                          SINISTRO, 
                          TARIFAS FROM (
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM TMP_CARGA_TIPO1_REGM 
                   PIVOT  (LISTAGG(COD_CONTEUDO, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) 
                   FOR (COD_INDICADOR) IN 
                                ( 'comprasoffusparceladascomjuros' COMPRAS_OFFUS_PARC_COM_JUROS, 
                                  'comprasoffusparceladassemjuros' COMPRAS_OFFUS_PARC_SEM_JUROS, 
                                  'comprasoffusavista' COMPRAS_OFFUS_AVISTA, 
                                  'comprasonusparceladascomjuros' COMPRAS_ONUS_PARC_COM_JUROS, 
                                  'comprasonusavista' COMPRAS_ONUS_AVISTA, 
                                  'comprasonusparceladassemjuros' COMPRAS_ONUS_PARC_SEM_JUROS, 
                                  'descontos' DESCONTOS, 
                                  'iof' IOF, 
                                  'juros' JUROS, 
                                  'multa' MULTA, 
                                  'outros' OUTROS, 
                                  'pagamentos' PAGAMENTOS, 
                                  'pagcontas' PAG_CONTAS, 
                                  'parcele' PARCELE, 
                                  'recupera' RECUPERA, 
                                  'saqueparcelado' SAQUE_PARCELADO, 
                                  'saqueavista' SAQUE_AVISTA, 
                                  'seguros' SEGUROS, 
                                  'sinistro' SINISTRO, 
                                  'tarifas' TARIFAS )));
```

mas para alguns caras, o pivot está colocando o valor em uma linha de baixo (a qual não deveria existir, apenas uma linha por registro)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note a coluna "Pagamentos", ele alimentou em uma linha em baixo em vez de cima.

Oq será que pode ser?

Registro original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: Traduza sua pergunta, pois este site é em português.

Comment: Não é um branco ? 'X ' <> 'X'